# Another way to run reports on a SpiceWorks SQLite database using a linked server in SSMS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I created a linked server in SSMS so that I could run reports on a SpiceWorks SQLite database.  there are a few quirks in the whole system.

These simple queries are becoming some of the most expensive queries on my reporting SQL Server, I kind of know why, is there a way that I can do this differently?

---

#### The Code

I have two queries.

1. TimeToCloseByAssignee

   ```
   SELECT 
       id AS ticketNum
       , Summary
       , Assignee
       , closed_at
       , created_at
       , ROUND((DATEDIFF(Hour, created_at, closed_at))/24. , 2) AS DaysOpen
   FROM OPENQUERY(SPICEWORKS,'
       SELECT tickets.id 
           , users.email as Assignee
           , substr(tickets . summary, 1,100) AS Summary
           , tickets.closed_at
           , tickets.created_at
       FROM tickets
           INNER JOIN users ON tickets.assigned_to = users.id
   WHERE status=''closed''
           AND 
           master_ticket_id IS NULL;')
   ```
2. GetCreatorByTicketID

   ```
   SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(SPICEWORKS, '
       SELECT users.email
           , tickets.id
       FROM tickets
           INNER JOIN users ON tickets.created_by = users.id')
   WHERE id = @TicketID
   ```

I am using SSRS to handle the nice presentation of the data.

the problem with this, is that I can't give the underlying SQLite query boundaries from SSRS Parameters, it just doesn't like it. There are some questions on StackOverflow with answers and ways to do it, but this was the only way that I could make it work the way I wanted it to.   perhaps I wasn't interpreting the answers correctly.  either way I don't think it would have been clean and straightforward anyway.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Just a minor suggestion, but maybe you could specify the columns to retrieve from the second query.

Comment: I mean, instead of using `SELECT *`, write the column names (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867946/sql-wildcard-performance-overhead). I'm well aware it's probably the least of the problems, though.

Comment: why would I type more code that could contain bugs than I have to? @ArthurChamz ?  I don't need to write out all the column names, this is a pass-through query. I know what I am getting, and it is going straight into a report from here.  I don't need more places where my dumb fingers can mistype something and cause issues on this.  thanks I like the idea but it isn't a good one (if that makes sense).

Comment: @ArthurChamz, I would agree with you if I was only writing the query in one spot, but I need all the fields that I select from the SQLite database and that won't change in this case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to remove the second query and merge it with the first one like this, I don't know why I didn't try it like this to begin with, probably because I wanted to tread lightly on this shaky bridge.   I still don't have a solid way of passing variables to the `OPENQUERY`, but that is a question perhaps for StackOverflow when I have more time to work on this project.

## Code:

```
SELECT 
    id AS ticketNum
    , Summary
    , Assignee
    , closed_at
    , created_at
    , Round((DATEDIFF(HOUR,created_at, closed_at))/24. , 2) AS DaysOpen
    , Creator
FROM OPENQUERY(SPICEWORKS, '
    SELECT tickets.id
        , users.email AS Assignee
        , substr(tickets . summary, 1,100) AS Summary
        , tickets.closed_at
        , tickets.created_at
        , table2.email AS Creator
    FROM
        tickets
        INNER JOIN users ON tickets.assigned_to = users.id
        INNER JOIN users AS table2 ON tickets.created_by = table2.id 
    WHERE tickets.status = ''closed'' AND tickets.master_ticket_id IS NULL;')
```

what I did here was turn the other query into a separate join to the `users` table but joined the aliased table on another field in the `tickets` table.  this way I can get both the creator and the assigned user (`Assignee`) from this single query.

getting rid of the second Query  reduced the amount of queries to the SQLite database to just one,  the other way was executing the second query an outrageous amount of times because the second query would run once for every row in the first query,  **THIS IS HORRIBLY INEFFICIENT**, do not do this unless you absolutely have to.

I should have explained more,  the second query had to be a sub-report of the first one in order for it to work the way I wanted it to.  I didn't think I could alias tables in a query run this way, I wasn't fully qualifying the names of all my columns once I put an alias in, and that is why I didn't do that the first go round, but now I know that I can do this on SQLite as long as I fully qualify all the columns I select in the query run on the SQLite database

Answer (score 6):

Ouch.... you are not filtering the data you are selecting from the OPENQUERY source....

But, let's get some things straight first.... you say:

> either way I don't think it would have been clean and straightforward anyway

Using OPENQUERY automatically excludes any pretext of *'clean and straightforward'*. They are incompatible.

So, as soon as you use OPENQUERY you can assume that you have already got ugly code (with a fat ass).

The trick is to use makeup - to cover up the blemishes.

In this case, you *can* filter the records, but you need to be creative.... you have:

> ```
> SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(SPICEWORKS, '
>     SELECT users.email
>         , tickets.id
>     FROM tickets
>         INNER JOIN users ON tickets.created_by = users.id')
> WHERE id = @TicketID
> ```

I would suggest the following:

```
declare @ticketsql as nvarchar(1024)
;

set @ticketsql = '
    SELECT users.email
        , tickets.id
    FROM tickets
        INNER JOIN users ON tickets.created_by = users.id
    WHERE tickets.id = ' + @TicketID
;

select * FROM OPENQUERY(SPICEWORKS, @ticketsql)
```

Comment: I tried this and couldn't get it to work, but I use a `VARCHAR(8000)` and not a `NVARCHAR(1024)`

Comment: I am going to try nesting queries to get rid of the second query altogether.

Comment: it doesn't like that @rolfl,  says `Incorrect syntax near '@TicketID`, Expecting STRING, or TEXT_LEX.`

Comment: `Convert(NVarchar(50), @TicketID)` instead when doing the concatenation

Comment: `OPENQUERY` doesn't like being passed a Variable there @rolfl  if I just put a string in there without the reference to a parameter it still doesn't like it.

Comment: I found a way to get rid of the one query, but I have no way of restricting the Date range if I want to go that route.  I will have to do it on the returned set.

Comment: I wonder why this doesn't work for me?